# How to expire Branch.io link within specific time? (Deep linking via branch metrics)

Tags: http, deep-linking, branch.io

I am using link to generate deep linking. I am using their public API's endpoint to generate links.

Here is their endpoint: https://api.branch.io/v1/url

I append my branch key and data that I need to associate in this link. Everything is working fine but I need to expire this link within one hour.

Reading up here: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api#creating-a-deep-linking-url

I added "duration" key also, but it didnt expire the link.

It will be great if anyone could help me in figuring out how to expire branch.io link.

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here: the `duration` parameter is used for something different, so it's not going to be able to do what you want. We don't have a built-in feature to expire links, but you could create something close to it yourself:

1. Add a custom link parameter containing a timestamp for when the link was created.
2. Check for that timestamp when handling the link at the destination, and do something different if it is more than an hour old. I'm guessing this would be inside your app, and also on whatever fallback URL you have specified for when the app isn't installed or the user is on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Mail from branch.io support team suggested this answer as below:

> If you found out about the $exp_date parameter from here then the
>   parameters in that list are only used for iOS Spotlight Indexing but
>   will be used by Branch in the future.  A better solution than
>   utilizing $exp_date is to code logic into your client to determine
>   what to do with link data based on date. This way, your deep links
>   will always work and always carry data through, and you won't have to
>   worry about users clicking empty links.
>
> This way, you would include date as an extra meta key/value pair, and
>   examine this date in your client when receiving link params to
>   determine if you want to honor the link's contents or not.